# Ember.js - Error - "Assertion failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`"

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting this error after I save a post (title, text) to a mongodb database via a REST API written with Express and refresh the browser. I've already set my primary key to '_id' and have been reading about possibly normalizing the data?

Here is the payload from the server (only 1 post in db):

```js
{
  "posts": [
  {
    "title": "The Title",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum",
    "_id": "52c22892381e452d1d000010",
    "__v": 0
   }
  ]
}
```

The controller:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
      createPost: function() {
        // Dummy content for now
        var to_post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
          title: 'The Title',
          text: 'Lorem ipsum'
        });
        to_post.save();
      }
    } 
 });
```

The model:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr('string'),
   text: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Serializer:

```
App.MySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: function(type){
    return '_id';
  }
});
```

Adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

Any help is much appreciated! Please let me know if you need any other info.
Thanks

Comment: how did you set the primaryKey?

Comment: @kingpin2k I used `DS.JSONSerializer.extend({ primaryKey: function(type) {return '_id';} });`

Comment: Would you mind showing the adapter and serializer code above?

Comment: @kingpin2k Sure, I added them to the bottom. It seems like I can retrieve the data, but I get an error for every single post that is returned from the api. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using custom adapters/serializers the naming is important.  If you want it to apply to the entire application it should be called `ApplicationSerializer`

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

If you just want it to apply to a single model (this applies to adapter's as well)

```
App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hadn't realized that. I updated the serializer but am still getting the error. Do you think the issue is because the mongo id has '_id' instead of just 'id' and Ember can't find the id?

Comment: I just realized the primary key was a function, it either should be a plain property (see above) or you should tack on `.property()` to the end of the function

Comment: Success! Thank you so much for your help! I added .property() and it works.

Comment: primaryKey is not being called in my app, perhaps this has to do with a new version of ember-data?

Comment: Please create a new question and include all of the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error but after some debugging discovered it was caused by my rest API not returning the saved objects json.