# extract to normalizeReponse issue

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am migrating ember & ember-data from 1.12 to 1.13. During same, I got deprecation message to rename `extract` methods as `normalizeResponse` of serializer. After doing same I am getting following error.

```
Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for list-item in an object passed to `push`
```

But there are few models for which I am adding ids in `extract` method. But now, ember is throwing above error for `normalizeResponse`. How can I correct same?

Comment: Possible duplicate issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850930/ember-js-error-assertion-failed-you-must-include-an-id-in-a-hash-passed

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: Please post your code.